# Trouble with Sequlize associations,

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Been having some trouble setting up associations with the sequelize library.  Keep getting SequelizeEagerLoadingError: Client is not associated to License!

Here are my two models.

```js
'use strict';

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const License = sequelize.define('License', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
      primaryKey: true,
      validate: { isUUID: 4 }
    },
    client_id: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      validate: { isUUID: 4 }
    }
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function (models) {
        License.belongsTo(models.Client, { foriegnKey: 'client_id' });
      }
    }
  });
  return License;
};
```

```js
'use strict';

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Client = sequelize.define('Client', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    name: { type: DataTypes.STRING }
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function (models) {
        Client.hasOne(models.License);
        Client.hasMany(models.Event);
        Client.hasMany(models.Clips);
      }
    }
  });
  return Client;
};
```

And here is the controller I have setup, I know the model is working correctly because I tested with the findbyID() function which works.

```js
'use strict';

const db = require('../models/index.js');

class Controller {
    constructor(router) {
        router.get('/:id', (req, res, next) => {

            // db.License.findById(req.params.id).then(function(license) {
            //     res.status(200).json(license);
            // }, function(err) {
            //     res.status(404).json({
            //         error: 'License does not exist!'
            //     });
            // });
            db.License.findAll({
                include: [{ model: db.Client }]
            })
            .then(function(license) {
                res.status(200).json(license);
            }, function(err) {
                console.log(err);
                res.status(404).json({
                    error: 'License does not exist!'
                });
            });
        });
    }
}

module.exports = router => new Controller(router);
```

Help would be great feeling super lost. sequelize.sync() is being run and isn't throwing any errors.  Trying to figure out if I have a naming issue maybe because something needs to be capitalized or not capitalized and it isn't.

Comment: Just realized the way I have my models setup doesn't work with V4 of sequelize so nothing was every getting associated.  I was using the default format from the sequelize cli migrations which doesn't work anymore it seems.

Comment: Did you resolved? You're redefining the foreign key on your models. First you do a belongsTo on License and then a hasOne on Client. belongsTo create the key on the origen model and hasOne on the target model, besides use `as` on the belongsTo option so when you do the include sequelize knows which key are you refering.

Comment: Yeah, I figured it out I should close the question.  None of my associations were being set up because of the new format for defining instance and class methods for models in sequelize V4.  And since I was running migrations to control my database and my column names I also had to go back and edit them to conform to what sequqlize was looking for.  client_id => ClientId

Answer (score 3):

I also face this kind of error in Sequelize v4+. I modify my models with some small change, Hope that will work for you.
Write Licence model like this

```js
'use strict';

module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
    const License = sequelize.define('License', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.UUID,
            defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
            primaryKey: true,
            validate: {isUUID: 4}
        },
        client_id: {
            type: DataTypes.UUID,
            validate: {isUUID: 4}
        }
    });
    License.associate = function (models) {
        License.belongsTo(models.Client, {foriegnKey: 'client_id'});
    };
    return License;
};
```

Same modify your Client as like this,

```js
'use strict';

module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
    const Client = sequelize.define('Client', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.UUID,
            defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        name: {type: DataTypes.STRING}
    });
    Client.associate = function (models) {
        Client.hasOne(models.License);
        Client.hasMany(models.Event);
        Client.hasMany(models.Clips);
    };

    return Client;
};
```